# How to store an array of colors in a database?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

[I need create this functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTlcS.png), I'm creating a clone of nike.com, and I have a problem. How to create a product table with color options? How should I store this data in the database (PostgreSQL + Sequelize)?
I already created two tables: Product and Color, and now I want to link them so, when creating the product table, I can add the existing colors from the Color table.

```
  async create(req: Request & { files: any }, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const { name, price, typeId, categoryId } = req.body
      const colors = [1, 2, 3]
      const { img } = req.files
      let fileName = uuidv4() + '.jpg' 
      img.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', fileName))
      const product = await Product.create({
        name,
        price,
        img: fileName,
        typeId,
        categoryId,
        colors: //[2, 1] how to select from colorTable?
      })
      return res.json(product)
    } catch (e) {
      next(ApiError.BadRequest(e.message))
    }
  }

const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  img: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  rating: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 },
})

const Color = sequelize.define('color', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  color: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
})


Color.belongsToMany(Product, { through: TypeColor })
Product.belongsToMany(Color, { through: TypeColor })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a many-to-many (M:M) is database terms. A product has many colors and a color is used by many products. This is resolved by creating a third table (Product_Color). This table contains the  ID of each of the base tables as its own PK and each as a FK to the appropriate table. I do not know Sequelize but in Postgres the table definitions something like.

```
create table products( 
             prod_id integer generated always as identity 
           , name    test 
           -- additional product atteibutes 
           , constraint products_pk
                        primary key(prod_id)           
           ); 

create table colors(
             color_id integer generated always as identity 
           , name     text 
           -- additional color attributs
           , constraint colors_pk
                        primary key(color_id)  
           ); 

          
-- Resolution table for M:M products:colors
create table product_colors(
             prod_id  integer 
           , color_id integer
           -- intersection attributes 
           , constraint products_colors_pk
                        primary key (prod_id,color_id)
           , constraint products_colors_2_products_fk
                        foreign key (prod_id) 
                        references products(prod_id)
           , constraint products_colors_2_colors_fk
                        foreign key (color_id) 
                        references colors(color_id)
           );
```

Do not store as an array. They are initially simple but attempting to do anything with them gets complicated quickly. Like listing colors by products. It violates 1NF form, see [here](https://www.datascienceacademy.io/blog/what-is-data-normalization-why-it-is-so-necessary/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for.
if you want to select colour in Color table, why don't you select before create Product?

Because you use async, i think calling color in table with async(color data what you want) makes no problem!

like below!!

```js
async create(req: Request & { files: any }, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const { name, price, typeId, categoryId } = req.body
      const colors = [1, 2, 3]
      const { img } = req.files
      let fileName = uuidv4() + '.jpg' 
      img.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', fileName))

     const color = await Color.findAll({
      where :{} // here goes with your conditions      
})
      const product = await Product.create({
        name,
        price,
        img: fileName,
        typeId,
        categoryId,
        colors: //[2, 1] how to select from colorTable?
      })
      return res.json(product)
    } catch (e) {
      next(ApiError.BadRequest(e.message))
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want one shoe(Product) to have multiple colors in the database, maybe i'm moving in the wrong direction, because i have never done it before and maybe there is a better way to solve this problem